# How to open ListItem hyperlink in separate window

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want the hyperlink, given as value of bulleted list item ,to open in separate window.
Currently it opens in the same window.

Comment: Show us your markup, have you tried adding target="_blank"?

Comment: Please show us some markup/what have you tried...

Answer (score 0):

Use the Target property and set it to "_blank":

[BulletedList.Target Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.bulletedlist.target.aspx)